# How to upgrade Galaxy Nexus from 4.0.1 to 4.0.4

Tags: updates, samsung-galaxy-nexus

I would like to know how to manually upgrade my Samsung Galaxy Nexus from Android version 4.0.1 to the latest 4.0.4.

I got this phone in Australia and it is currently running the "yakjudv" build rather than the standard "yakju" build. My understanding it that the "yakju" build is the standard one produced by Google and that the "yakjudv" build is one produced by my carrier and hence why I am not getting the standard Google updates.

I am prepared to move to the standard Google build if it is easier.

Comment: If you use CyanogenMod, you can see this tutorial.
Hope it can help you. http://thesuperusersguide.weebly.com/how-to-flash-a-rom.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to move to the standard Google build, you have to root your Nexus to bypass the signature verification. Otherwise you can't go to the Google build.
I have a Nexus One and it's the same thing. Before, i can get the Google OTA, i had to root my phone.